# Delete a row from db after it has existed for 3 minutes. SQL

Tags: sql

```
CREATE EVENT delete_views
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 SECOND_MICROSECOND
    DO BEGIN
      DELETE views WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MINUTE_SECOND);
    END;
```

I got this code above from another stackoverflow post and it does not work.

When I say it doesn't work I mean that there is an error that says there is a syntax error near `WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MINUTE_SECOND)`

(This is for a function so that it makes it so that people can not spam a post and get a bunch of views for it). But in otherwords, I want to have an event that repeats itself every second or microsecond (doesn't matter that much it just has to be a very short time) and it will delete a row that has existed for over 3 minutes in a table (views).

The table row contains the columns: user_id, video_id, date (current time stamp)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should attach the links of other posts you have referenced.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and there is no `CREATE EVENT` in standard SQL). [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: @coolpigeon2122 . . . This is usually a really bad idea -- just a way of overloading a database with unnecessary transactions, particularly at peak volumes.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using xammp, so I think I'm using mariadb, not sure entirely.

Comment: @GordonLinoff is there a better way of doing this? Becuase I was thinking about using cookies instead but some people could just disable them.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name A mysql server

Comment: @GordonLinoff Maybe in my php code, I could possible store wat videos people have viewed in a session array and when people sign out, the session does not get destroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't delete rows, randomly through the day.  Just control access to the data through a view:

```
create view v_t as
    select t.*
    from t
    where t.date > now() - interval 3 minute;
```

Voila!  Only the most recent data is available.

You can then `delete` (if necessary) at your leisure, preferably in off-hours when the load on the database is minimal.

Comment: So then below that code  `where t.date > now() - interval 3 minute;`, I can add the delete function? I'm not too familair with this so I'll do some research on my own. Also if you have any helpful links I'd gladly appreciate them.

Comment: I think I understand it a little bit more. If I use this code, will I have to then type in manually something like this: `DELETE v_t `? If so, this is not exactly what I want as I want the rows to be deleted automatically after they have existed for 3 minutes. I think I might just use two session arrays that will be checked every time someone clicks on a video.

Comment: @coolpigeon2122 . . . All selects would select from the view.  The older records would never be seen.  That is about as good as deleting the rows.